# Fragment not showing up

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

I'm having an issue where I can create a Fragment, its view appears to be created, but it doesn't show up. The fragment itself is created and any code inside runs without issue, but it is just invisible somewhere. The back button also interacts with it just fine (it "closes" it), it just doesn't physically show up on screen (only the main layout is displayed).

From my FragmentActivity:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_view);

    // some logic here that sets a button listener that calls openAddNamePane() when pressed
}

public void openAddNamePane(){
    AddNamePane addNamePane = new AddNamePane();
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.layout_root, addNamePane, "AddnamePane");
    fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
    fragmentTransaction.commit();
}
```

This is the layout for the View that is first displayed (activity_main_view.xml aka my 'root layout'):

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"

    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"

    android:orientation="vertical"

    android:background="@color/white"
    android:id="@+id/layout_root">

    <LinearLayout 
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <Button android:id="@+id/addPlayerButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Add Player" />

        <Button android:id="@+id/button2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/buttonLabel" />
    </LinearLayout>


    <ListView android:id="@+id/playerListView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:cacheColorHint="@color/white"
        android:entries="@array/testStringArray" >
    </ListView>

</LinearLayout>
```

This is my fragment class:

```
public class AddNamePane extends Fragment {
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        System.out.println("AddNamePane.onCreateView()");

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.add_player_pane_layout, container, false);

        return view;
    }

    // a few other methods here, onAttach(), onStop(), onPause(), etc
    // all are empty of logic with just a println to see if they are being called correctly (in which they are)
}
```

This is the layout for that "AddNamePane" fragment:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"

    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"

    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10" 
        android:text="test name here"
        android:hint="Name here" >
        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button" />

</LinearLayout>
```

I am pretty new to using fragments, not too sure if my issue is in code or if it is something to do with the layouts. My goal is to add the "AddNamePane" to the 'root layout' replacing the main view temporarily. What I did to attempt this was to give my root layout an id and use that in the FragmentTransaction. If it matters, the api level I am using is 8 (Android 2.2) thus using things from android.support.v4.app package.

Comment: Have you tried creating a `fragment holder` type FrameLayout or similar in your root layout to display your fragment? Then in your code you would reference that new element - `fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragmentHolder, addNamePane, "AddnamePane");`

Comment: By trying to attach directly 'over top' of my main layout, I was hoping to reduce a 'layer' by reusing my main layout as a parent/root for the other fragments. But seems like Paul is saying this is not allowed.

Answer (score 19):

You're trying to programmatically replace a `LinearLayout`, while also expecting it to have the hard-coded children. This won't work. You should use a `FrameLayout` for your `FragmentTransaction` that is also a child of your `layout_root`.

If you update your post with the actual xml, I can show you exactly how to do this.

Comment: Hi Paul, I added the rest of the layout xml, though later it'll probably change a bit as I add a few more things (but I can figure that out when the time comes). In short, it seems that having a 'root view' that contains stuff just cannot be used to attach another view/fragment over top of it? It results in the hardcoded view always taking precedence and instead I should have a root (that contains "nothing") and attach my first/main view on that any fragments also attach to that root as well? Hm, I don't think I've used a 'FrameLayout' before.

Comment: Oh wait a min. Rereading your answer the next day it looks like I had it backwards: you're suggesting I add a 'container' of sorts (a FrameLayout element) in to my main view and append my fragments to that. I did try something like this, but what I had put in (another LinearLayout I think), ended up taking over the screen and pushing all my original root elements out. I had set this to take up the entire screen as I wanted my fragment to take up the entire screen. I shall take a look at FrameLayout.

Comment: Could you set the size paramaters of the frame-layout once you complete the fragment transaction?

Comment: After a bit of fiddling, my fragment appears now, though it appears at the top and pushes the main view's contents down as opposed to appearing overtop and taking up the screen. What I'm really desiring is that the fragment just appears over top and covers up the initial view's contents. Any idea how to get to this?

Comment: Long time I know but this was exactly the case with me and I literally spent two days pulling my hair! Thanks for the short answer. :)

Comment: You saved my life man, thanks so much. I was facing https://stackoverflow.com/q/37602606/3749773

Answer (score 6):

I had a similar problem, when fragment wasn't showing up. The problem was that I removed AndroidAnnotations, but forgot to move the code from onViewCreated and onCreate methods to the onCreateView. I found this mistake by comparing the code of two fragments - one, that was showing up and the other that wasn't. So, if you have similar problems, try to check the code of fragments. It may not show any errors at first glance, but will not still work or show up because of those errors.

Particularly, check that you have this method and that you inflate a view:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.your_fragment_layout, container, false);
    return v;

}
```

Comment: In my case I updated this method and forgot to return the inflated view and was returning null !

Answer (score 0):

```
tools:layout="@layout/fragment_up"
```

Use your layout file as above