# Replacing Fragment Inside of ViewPager Opens the Fragment in ViewPager Dimensions

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

Fragment A contains `ViewPager` which has Fragment B. Fragment B contains a `RecyclerView` and clicking on its items, opens Fragment C.

**Open Fragment C (implemented by Fragment B)**

```
private void openItemPage(long id) {
        Fragment a2Fragment = CompanyPageFragment.newInstance(id);
        FragmentTransaction transaction = getChildFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

        // store the Fragment in stack
        transaction.addToBackStack(null);
        transaction.replace(R.id.container, a2Fragment).commit();
    }
```

**Fragment A Layout**

```
<LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingTop="15dp">

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            android:background="@drawable/top_bottom_border"
            app:tabBackground="@android:color/transparent"
            app:tabIndicatorHeight="0dp"
            app:tabMode="fixed">
        </android.support.design.widget.TabLayout>

        <ir.barandeh.android.views.NonSwipeableViewPager
            android:id="@+id/pager"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:overScrollMode="never"/>
    </LinearLayout>
```

**Fragment B Layout**

```
<RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/container"
                xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.v4.widget.ContentLoadingProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/contentLoading"
        style="?android:attr/android:progressBarStyle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"/>

    <android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
        android:id="@+id/refresh"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/recycler"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:overScrollMode="never"
            android:paddingEnd="10dp"
            android:paddingStart="10dp">

        </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>

    </android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

**Fragment C Layout**

```
<RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="?android:attr/windowBackground">

            <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:fillViewport="true"
                app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

                <ir.barandeh.android.views.NonSwipeableViewPager
                    android:id="@+id/pager"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:overScrollMode="never"/>
            </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

    </RelativeLayout>
```

The problem is, Fragment C content is shown inside of the `ViewPager` not whole Fragment A layout.

Comment: We can't see the layout for fragment B, but my guess would be that the R.id.container is used for more than one `ViewGroup`. Check that R.id.container is not the id of one of the views in the `RecyclerView` etc. You can also use the view hierarchy tool to check where the new fragment is placed and what it is replacing instead of what you expected.

Comment: @frozenkoi I updated my question with fragments layouts. Can you review the layouts please? removing ids didn't help.

Comment: All 3 layouts have root with the `container` id. What class does `openItemPage` belong to? That will be important so that you can be clear about what fragment manager is being used for replacing fragments. Note that the docs for `getChildFragmentManager` ( https://d.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#getChildFragmentManager() ) say that it returns a manager for placing inside the current fragment, contrast with `getFragmentManager` which  returns a manager for the upper level. So if the `openItemPage` function is part of the fragment B, it won't see the parent `container`.

Comment: @frozenkoi You're absolutely right about Fragment B cannot see Fragment A container but what about `getParentFragment().getChildFragmentManager()`? It should have access now, right? but replacing would not be done at all!

Comment: You need to clarify which of all of the `container`s is supposed to be replaced by the new Fragment C. If the entire fragment A is meant to be replaced by Fragment C, then I think you need to do something like `fragmentA.getFragmentManager()` to get it's parent's manager.

Comment: @frozenkoi Didn't work unfortunately.

Comment: @frozenkoi I found the problem and posted the right answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> You're trying to programmatically replace a `LinearLayout`, while also
>   expecting it to have the hard-coded children. This won't work. You
>   should use a `FrameLayout` for your `FragmentTransaction` that is also a
>   child of your `layout_root`.

Quoted from https://stackoverflow.com/a/18885196/3749773. Thanks to [Paul Burke](https://stackoverflow.com/users/377260/paul-burke)

Another mistake was calling `getChildFragmentManager()` from Fragment B but I had to call it from Fragment A. Thanks to [frozenkoi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/599926/frozenkoi)